# Format a duration in days hours minutes in Excel

Tags: excel, formatting, duration

I have the following cells :

| A (Start) | A+C (End) | C (Duration) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Friday 09/02/2024 14:00 | Wednesday 14/02/2024 14:00 | 4D 00H00 |
| Wednesday 14/02/2024 14:00 | #VALUE! | 30/12/1899 03:00:00 |

The value C1 row corresponds to a duration of 4 days and
the value C2 row corresponds to a duration of 3 hours.

The format used for A and B is "dddd dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm" and that for column C is "d"D "hh"H"mm".

When I double click to edit cell C2 and type Enter, I get a "#VALUE!" error in cell B2.

I expect this :

| A (Start) | A+C (End) | C (Duration) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Friday 09/02/2024 14:00 | Wednesday 14/02/2024 14:00 | 4D 00H00 |
| Wednesday 14/02/2024 14:00 | Wednesday 14/02/2024 18:00 | 0D 03H00 |

Comment: 3 hours is equivalent to 1/8 or 0.125. What's the *value* you're using in C2?

Comment: @BigBen C2=04/01/1900  00:00:00

Comment: That looks like C1, not C2. Maybe better said, what is the value you're using for a duration of 3 hours?

Comment: @BigBen Oups sorry : C2=30/12/1899  03:00:00

Comment: Use `0.125` instead. Or `0/1/1900 03:00:00`

Comment: @BigBen Then "30D 03H00" is displayed

Comment: @BigBen If I type "0/1/1900 03:00:00" , then I get a `#VALUE` error in B2.

Comment: I'm unable to repro either of these. I've used `=1/8` or `0.125` or `0/1/1900 3:00AM` (since my regional settings are month/day not day/month), and I get `0D 03H00` in C2.

Comment: @BigBen If I try typing "1/0/1900 03:00:00", I get a `#VALUE` also.

Comment: @BigBen If I type `=1/8`, then `30D 03H00` is displayed instead of `0D 03H00`.

Comment: Not sure how you expect 14:00 + 3h to be 18:00 but I can't reproduce your problem either. Can you re-enter your values and check again? Don't type "1/0/1900 03:00:00", type `0,125` (`=1/8` should technically work still). Don't forget to re-enter your date as well in case there's some hidden characters screwing up the A-value.

Comment: I hope you realize the the format you are using for Column C will not display days accurately for Days > 31. I, too, cannot reproduce your problem using your technique. However, your posted format for `C` cannot be correct, and, as noted by @Notus_Panda, your addition seems to be incorrect for both rows.